# Get table cell id from rowid

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp, html-table

I have a table with two rows and three columns:

```
<table>
  <tr id='a'>
    <td id='aa'>Cell A</td>
    <td id='ab'>Cell B</td>
    <td id='ac'>Cell C</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id='b'>
    <td id='ba'>Cell A</td>
    <td id='bb'>Cell B</td>
    <td id='bc'>Cell C</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

How can I get all the `<td>` ids under a particular `<tr>` using javascript or jquery?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you cannot get all td ids once you you to loop through.

Comment: Why to use `id`s, `tr`s have `rowIndex` property, and `td`s have `cellIndex` property.

Comment: you may use class attribute for tr and id for td  Class Selector (“.class”)

Selects all elements with the given class.

Comment: jQuery has selectors for that. See http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ and http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should loop through all tds inside a row  this code for example to get td ids from #a

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('table #a td').each(function(){
        alert($(this).attr('id'));
    });
});
```

SEE [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/hep7fb1q/7/)

Answer (score 3):

you should loop through all tds inside a row

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('table #a td').each(function(){
        alert($(this).attr('id'));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Get all IDs of `<td>`s under `<tr id='a'>` this way:

```js
$('#a td').each(function(td){
  console.log($(this).attr('id'));  // check your console after running this
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr id='a'>
    <td id='aa'>Cell A</td>
    <td id='ab'>Cell B</td>
    <td id='ac'>Cell C</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id='b'>
    <td id='ba'>Cell A</td>
    <td id='bb'>Cell B</td>
    <td id='bc'>Cell C</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

If you want it for the other row, just change the `<tr>` ID.

Learn more:

- [`.each()` | jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/each/)
- [`.attr()` | jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map) which return an array of matched id's as shown below:

```js
var idArray = $('#a td').map(function(i,elm) {
  return elm.id;
}).get();
console.log(idArray);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr id='a'>
    <td id='aa'>Cell A</td>
    <td id='ab'>Cell B</td>
    <td id='ac'>Cell C</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id='b'>
    <td id='ba'>Cell A</td>
    <td id='bb'>Cell B</td>
    <td id='bc'>Cell C</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```